OCR and pytesseract detecting numbers in an image
currentbid.png:

I am trying to detect the number in this image and it gives me letters or the wrong number.
This is my image i am trying to detect the number ive tried tons of stuff with greyscale and inversion using tesseract but nothing seems to work it keeps giving me letters like ADA or the wrong number like if the image said 98.7M it would give me 19 9947 )M and i think that the period is messing it up but im unable to remove it or change the font. How can I fix it or train it?
Here is my current code:
pyautogui.screenshot("bidpossible.png", region=(900, 310, 450, 60)) #bidpossible
originalImage = cv2.imread('bidpossible.png')


grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(originalImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(_, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

custom_config = r'--psm 8'


text = pytesseract.image_to_string(blackAndWhiteImage, config=custom_config)
print('Extracted Text: ', text)


how about using filter that will try to get only light-blue color that is inside text boundary?

grayImage[(grayImage<210)] = 255
grayImage[(grayImage>210) & (grayImage<230)] = 0


# test different models, imho models 6 or 7 work better
custom_config = f'--psm 7' 
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(grayImage, config=custom_config)
print(f'Extracted Text: ', text) # 4.34m_


Thank you but now im also having trouble detecting white text with a black outline that is on a white background it spits out something close to the word. So i tried a word list to detect what word is closest to it. Which works sometimes but it is unreliable. How could i go about reading it better?

Could you pls add a new picture to the question? Let me know if it is more complex than the first one.

Honestly tessarect is not the best option for complex text recognition tasks. It could make a bit more sense to switch to Neural Nets, for example to mocr library: https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmocr/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file
